# Python unittest stops working when all test run together but individual tests work just fine

Tags: python, unit-testing

I'm learning how to use a unittest module and I came across something really annoying. I wrote this simple class.

```py
class Employee:

    salary = 0
    savings = 0
    no_of_emp = 0
    eid = -1
    raise_amount = 0
    tags = set()

    def __init__(self, first, last, salary=None):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.salary = salary or self.salary
        Employee.no_of_emp += 1
        self.eid = Employee.gen_eid()

    @staticmethod
    def gen_eid():
        from random import random
        return round(random() * 10000000000000)

    def get_email(self):
        return f"{self.first}.{self.last}@gmail.com"

    def set_salary(self, pay):
        self.salary = pay

    def give_raise(self):
        new_salary = self.raise_amount * self.salary
        self.salary = new_salary
        return new_salary

    def add_savings(self, amount):
        self.savings += amount

    def add_tag(self, t):
        self.tags.add(t)

    def remove_tag(self, t):
        self.tags.remove(t)

    @classmethod
    def set_raise_amount(cls, amount):
        cls.raise_amount = amount

    @classmethod
    def from_string(cls, emp_str):
        try:
            first, last, salary = tuple(emp_str.split('-'))
            return cls(first, last, salary)
        except ValueError:
            print(f"Incorrect amount of arguments!!: {emp_str}")
            import sys
            sys.exit(1)
```

...and also this unit test which is supposed to test it

```
import unittest
from Employee import Employee


class TestEmployee(unittest.TestCase):

    def tearDown(self):
        self.no_of_emp = 0
        print("Setting number of emp to 0")

    def test_it_returns_email_address(self):
        # assume
        first_name = 'john'
        last_name = 'smith'
        emp = Employee(first_name, last_name)

        # action
        result = emp.get_email()

        # assert
        self.assertEqual(result, "john.smith@gmail.com")

    def test_returns_eid(self):
        # assume
        first_name = 'john'
        last_name = 'smith'
        emp = Employee(first_name, last_name)

        # action
        result = emp.eid
        length = len(str(result))

        # assert
        self.assertNotEqual(result, -1)
        self.assertGreater(length, 8)
        self.assertIsInstance(result, int)

    def test_default_values(self):
        # assume
        first_name = 'john'
        last_name = 'smith'
        emp = Employee(first_name, last_name)
        emp2 = Employee(first_name, last_name)

        # action
        _salary = emp.salary
        _savings = emp.savings
        _tags = len(emp.tags)

        # assert
        self.assertEqual(_salary, 0)
        self.assertEqual(_savings, 0)
        self.assertEqual(emp.no_of_emp, 2)
        self.assertEqual(emp2.raise_amount, 0)
        self.assertEqual(_tags, 0)

    def test_adding_tags_works(self):
        # assume
        first_name = 'john'
        last_name = 'smith'
        emp = Employee(first_name, last_name)

        # action
        emp.add_tag('boss')
        _tags = len(emp.tags)

        # assert
        self.assertEqual(_tags, 1)
        self.assertEqual(emp.tags, {'boss'})


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

And the problem I'm having is that when I run my tests one by one they work as intended but when I run them all together it throws an error as such:

```
Ran 4 tests in 0.005s
FAILED (failures=1)
2 != 3

Expected :3
Actual   :2
File "/home/mike/PycharmProjects/class_example/tests/test_employee.py", line 53, in test_default_values
    self.assertEqual(emp.no_of_emp, 2)
```

It seems to me it somehow doesn't delete object instances after each class method is run, thus the no_of_emp keeps growing... but I was under the impression it will start each test with a clean plate class

Comment: This kind of thing is one of the reasons that it's a bad idea to have a class keep track of its instances. If that kind of tracking is needed, it should be some other code's responsibility.

Comment: okay, so what you're saying is that all those functions assertIsEqual() shouldn't be placed outside a class?

Comment: I mean that `no_of_emp` isn't a thing that `Employee` should be tracking.

Comment: right, so how do I add a property that will tell me how many instances of a class there are ? Like a shared property that increases every time I add a new class instance and reduces when I delete an instance

Comment: If you're storing instances in a list, you can call `len`. If you're using some more complex data structure, you can do whatever's appropriate for that data structure. If you've just got 2 variables, the count is 2. Note that none of this involves any attempt to manage a global count. You don't need a count of all instances that exist anywhere in the program - thinking you do is a common newbie design mistake.

Comment: okay, didn't know it gets so complicate din Python. In C++ you can implement static variables in a class: As the variables declared as static are initialized only once as they are allocated space in separate static storage so, the static variables in a class are shared by the objects.

Comment: Its exactly the same in python. Class variables are just like static class variables in C++. But in python its more difficult to use a destructor.

Comment: Even with more reliable destruction in C++, this is still almost always a bad idea, though.

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean to reset the global in setup?

```py
    def setUp(self):
        Employee.no_of_emp = 0
        print("Setting number of emp to 0")
```

Comment: yeah, I read about setUp() and tearDown() and thought it might help but it didn't (in this form anyway). I also doesn't work if I comment it out

Comment: Didn't help? With `setUp()` I get a different set of errors. Could it be that `setUp` is the way to go, but you have a real error somewhere?

Comment: Did you mean to add: `Employee.tags = set()` into `setUp`? This way I get all four tests passing.

Comment: hmm...I think the issue would be also that when I delete an instance the no_of_emp doesn't have a way to reduce it by 1. I just realized that I only keep increasing it automatically every time I spawn an instance. Maybe that is actually causing an issue

Comment: So what is the reason you need to keep track of the number of `Employee`s?

Comment: just want to have a way of telling how many class instances are there. It's like a property shared across all class instances